# Python destructor basing on try/finally + yield?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, generator, destructor, yield

I've been testing a dirty hack inspired by this http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html .
The main idea is to bring try/finally idea onto class level and get reliable and simple class destructor.

```
class Foo():
  def __init__(self):
    self.__res_mgr__ = self.__acquire_resources__()
    self.__res_mgr__.next()

  def __acquire_resources__(self):
    try:
      # Acquire some resources here
      print "Initialize"
      self.f = 1
      yield
    finally:
      # Release the resources here
      print "Releasing Resources"
      self.f = 0

f = Foo()
print "testing resources"
print f.f
```

But it always gives me:

```
Initialize
testing resources
1
```

and never "Releasing Resources". I'm basing my hope on:

> As of Python version 2.5, the yield statement is now allowed in the
>   try clause of a try ... finally construct. If the generator is not
>   resumed before it is finalized (by reaching a zero reference count or
>   by being garbage collected), the generator-iterator’s close() method
>   will be called, allowing any pending finally clauses to execute. [Source link](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement)

But it seems when the class member is being garbage collected together with the class their ref counts don't decrease, so as a result generators close() and thus finally is never called. As for the second part of the quote

> "or by being garbage collected"

I just don't know why it's not true. Any chance to make this utopia work? :)

BTW this works on module level:

```
def f():
  try:
    print "ack"
    yield
  finally:
    print "release"

a = f()
a.next()
print "testing"
```

Output will be as I expect:

```
ack
testing
release
```

NOTE: In my task I'm not able to use WITH manager because I'm releasing the resource inside end_callback of the thread (it will be out of any WITH). So I wanted to get a reliable destructor for cases when callback won't be called for some reason

Comment: There's no guarantee that anything left when the program ends will be garbage-collected and no guarantee their destructors will run.

Comment: @user2357112, so why this always works on module level and never on class?

Comment: Arbitrary implementation decisions. You shouldn't rely on either version working.

Comment: What exactly do you hope to gain from these contortions, compared to just defining `__del__`?

Comment: @delnan I was hoping it will be deterministic, because unlike for >__del__ I didn't find any mentions that yield+try/finally can be not executed.

Comment: Well, it's not, essentially because it's just fancy syntax for `__del__`. Generators are objects too and must be finalized by the same means as other objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is caused by a reference cycle and an implicit `__del__` defined on your generator (it's so implicit, [CPython doesn't actually show `__del__` when you introspect, because only the C level `tp_del` exists, no Python-visible `__del__` is created](https://bugs.python.org/issue17468)). Basically, when a generator has a `yield` inside:

- A `try` block, or equivalently
- A `with` block

it has an implicit `__del__`-like implementation. On Python 3.3 and earlier, if a reference cycle contains an object whose class implements `__del__` (technically, has `tp_del` in CPython), unless the cycle is manually broken, the cyclic garbage collector cannot clean it up, and just sticks it in `gc.garbage` (`import gc` to gain access), because it doesn't know which objects (if any) must be collected first to clean up "nicely".

Because your class's `__acquire_resources__(self)` contains a reference to the instance's `self`, you form a reference cycle:

`self` -> `self.__res_mgr__` (generator object) -> generator frame (referencing locals which includes) -> `self`

Because of this reference cycle, and the fact that the generator has a `try`/`finally` in it (creating `tp_del` equivalent to `__del__`), the cycle is uncollectable, and your `finally` block never gets executed unless you manually advance `self.__res_mgr__` (which defeats the whole purpose).

You experiment happens to display this problem automatically because the reference cycle is implicit/automatic, but any accidental reference cycle where an object in the cycle has a class with `__del__` will trigger the same problem, so even if you just did:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        # Acquire some resources here
        print "Initialize"
        self.f = 1

    def __del__(self):
        # Release the resources here
        print "Releasing Resources"
        self.f = 0
```

if the "resources" involved could conceivably lead to a reference cycle with an instance of `Foo`, you'd have the same problem.

The solution here is one or both of:

1. Make your class [a context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) so users provide the information necessary for deterministic finalization (by using `with` blocks) as well as providing an explicit cleanup method (e.g. `close`) for when `with` blocks aren't feasible (part of another object's state that is cleaned up through its own resource management). This is also the only way to provide deterministic cleanup on most non-CPython interpreters where reference counting semantics have never been used (so all finalizers are called non-deterministically, if at all)
2. Move to Python 3.4 or higher, where [PEP 442](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/) resolves the issue with uncollectable cyclic garbage (it's technically still possible to produce such cycles on CPython, but only via third party extensions that continue to use `tp_del` instead of updating to use the `tp_finalize` slot that allows cyclic garbage to be cleaned properly). It's still non-deterministic cleanup (if a reference cycle exists, you're waiting on the cyclic gc to run, sometime), but it's *possible*, where pre-3.4, cyclic garbage of this sort could not be cleaned up at all.