# How are context managers in unconsumed generators finalized?

Tags: python, generator, contextmanager

I do not understand how and when a context manager in a non-finished generator is closed. Consider the following context manager and function:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def ctx():
    print('enter ctx')
    yield
    print('exit ctx')

def gen_nums(n):
    with ctx():
        yield from range(n)
```

My first intuition was that if I call `gen_nums` but do not consume the generator fully, `ctx` will never be closed, which was rather concerning. For example:

```
for i, j in zip(range(5), gen_nums(10)):
    print(f'{i}, {j}')
```

Here `exit ctx` is *not* printed at the end. As I saw it, that meant that if I had a file context in the generator it would be left open; however I then realized that doing the same with files would actually close the file properly. After some tests, I found out that if I did:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def ctx():
    print('enter ctx')
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        print('exit ctx')
```

Now `exit ctx` was printed at the end. So I suppose some exception would be triggered at some point, but I don't know which, where or when (I tried to print the exception with `except BaseException as e` but it did not work). It seems it happens when the generator is deleted, because if I do:

```
g = gen_nums(10)
for i, j in zip(range(5), g):
    print(f'{i}, {j}')
del g
```

Then `exit ctx` only happens after `del g`. However, I would like to have a better understanding of what is happening here and who is triggering what.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python destructor basing on try/finally + yield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297026/python-destructor-basing-on-try-finally-yield)

Comment: Take a look at the tagged thread, it might not be a full duplicate but seems relevant to your query.  Namely, when the `del g` is executed, I suspect `__del__` is somewhat equivalent to `g.close()` which terminates the generator *without a StopIteration* to allow releasing the resources within the context manager.  Consequently, since the Generator isn't throwing an error, there's nothing for `ctx` to catch in the `try... except`.  If however you did `g.throw(SomeError)` during its lifetime, you *will* see `ctx` catch that error.

Comment: However I am unable to fully replicate a mock Generator class to expose the inner works to confirm my suspicions, so I can't fully provide an answer.  The general flow that I understand here is `g` is created, `ctx.__enter__()` is triggered, `g.send()` and etc while running the generator, and then `g.close()` or equivalent happens, and returns to `ctx.__exit__()` (which takes in whatever error was thrown).

Comment: @Idlehands Thank you for the link. It does not exactly solve the question but it has the pointers to solve it. What happens is that, as you suggest, deleting an unfinished generator will call its `stop` method, and that will raise a `GeneratorExit` exception, which will be raised to the context manager. In fact, if I replace the `finally:` in the second version of `ctx` with `except GeneratorExit:` it also works (I had tried to print the raised exception before unsuccessfully, because printing a `GeneratorExit` shows nothing).

Comment: @Idlehands I think it's okay to keep the question because it's not really the same as the other one, but maybe you should post the complete answer since you actually found about it, if that's okay with you.

Comment: Oh wait that might be wrong actually. If you if you do `c = ctx(); c.__enter__(); del c` you get the `GeneratorExit` exception. Actually both `@contextmanager`s an generators raise `GeneratorExit` when they are deleted before finishing, I'm just not sure here which one raises first.

Comment: Oddly enough I can't even do `c.__enter__()`, it's complaining `TypeError: '_GeneratorContextManager' object is not an iterator` for me.  I wanted some clarity between which of the `ctx` or `g` is raising the `GeneratorExit` yb adding some description, but I'm just not well versed enough to dive that far yet.  Might have to build my own `Ctx` with `__enter__` `__exit__` methods.  I'm hesitant to provide a half-arsed answer that I don't fully understand well myself so that's why I left it as a comment in hope of others to clarify for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
@contextmanager
def ctx():
    print('enter ctx')
    try:
        print('ctx begins yield')
        yield
        print('ctx finishes yield')
    finally:    
        print('exit ctx')

def gen_nums(n):
    print('entering generator')
    l = range(n)
    with ctx():
        print('inside context manager')
        for i in l:
            print('gen before yield')
            yield i
            print('gen after yield')
        print('existing ctx')
    print('exiting generator')
```

The result is thus:

```
>>> g = gen_nums(3)
>>> next(g)
entering generator
enter ctx
ctx begins yield
inside context manager
gen before yield
0
>>> next(g)
gen after yield
gen before yield
1
>>> next(g)
gen after yield
gen before yield
2
>>> next(g)
gen after yield
exiting ctx
ctx finishes yield
exit ctx
exiting generator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#165>", line 1, in <module>
    next(g)
StopIteration
```

It seems like the `contextmanager` is only ever truly exited at the point *after* the `generator`'s last iteration and before it hits `StopIteration`.  So at the very last iteration of the `generator` the `contextmanager` would remain open if it wasn't ran in a for loop (which handles the `StopIteration`).

You wouldn't be able to catch the `StopIteration` within the `contextmanager` either because it happens *after* the `generator` is exhausted, at which point the `contextmanager` would have been exited already.

Also, IIRC, in constructing a `contextmanager` you should always utilize `try... finally...` anyways.

Comment: I know the context is exited normally if the generator reaches `StopIteration`. My question is about the case where this does not happen. For example, `g = gen_nums(3); next(g); del g` would still print `exit ctx`, and I want to know how that works. `finally` is indeed frequently used in context managers, although I used it in case there was an exception within the `with` block; what I am pointing out that it is important also with generators, even if no exceptions are raised (explicitly, at least).